# Efficiently fill values between dates

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following dataset in which the value in column "value" is valid from the start until the end date:

```
data.table(company = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), person = c("a", "b", "b", "c"), value = c(2,3,5,5), start_date = c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-02", "2015-01-06"), end_date = c("2015-01-06", "2015-01-07", "2015-01-07", "2015-01-07"))
   company person value start_date   end_date
1:       A      a     2 2015-01-01 2015-01-06
2:       A      b     3 2015-01-04 2015-01-07
3:       B      b     5 2015-01-02 2015-01-07
4:       B      c     5 2015-01-06 2015-01-07
```

I would like to calculate three things based on this data:

1. the average value per company per date
2. the number of companies per date
3. the number of people per company per date

I have tried the following which works like a charm for my test sample, but it fails miserably in on the actual dataset as it is requires a lot of computing power. I know that it is caused by making a dataset with a separate row per company per person per date, however, I don't know how to get around this using some kind of function in R.

Tried code:

```
test$start_date = as.Date(as.character(test$start_date), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
test$end_date = as.Date(as.character(test$end_date), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
#indexing per row
indxtest = test[,.(Date=seq(from = min(start_date), to = max(end_date), by = "day")), by = 1:nrow(test)]

test = test[, nrow := 1:nrow(test)]
test = merge(indxtest, test, by =  "nrow", all.x = TRUE)

setDT(test, "company","Date")
test = test[, mean_EPS := mean(value, na.rm = TRUE), by = c("company", "Date")]
test = test[, Number_people := .N, by = c("company", "Date")]
test = test[, number_companies := uniqueN(company), by = "Date"]
```

my current outcome would look something like:

```
    nrow       Date company person value start_date   end_date mean_value Number_people number_companies
 1:    1 2015-01-01       A      a     2 2015-01-01 2015-01-06      2.0             1                1
 2:    1 2015-01-02       A      a     2 2015-01-01 2015-01-06      2.0             1                2
 3:    3 2015-01-02       B      b     5 2015-01-02 2015-01-07      5.0             1                2
 4:    1 2015-01-03       A      a     2 2015-01-01 2015-01-06      2.0             1                2
 5:    3 2015-01-03       B      b     5 2015-01-02 2015-01-07      5.0             1                2
 6:    1 2015-01-04       A      a     2 2015-01-01 2015-01-06      2.5             2                2
 7:    2 2015-01-04       A      b     3 2015-01-04 2015-01-07      2.5             2                2
 8:    3 2015-01-04       B      b     5 2015-01-02 2015-01-07      5.0             1                2
 9:    1 2015-01-05       A      a     2 2015-01-01 2015-01-06      2.5             2                2
10:    2 2015-01-05       A      b     3 2015-01-04 2015-01-07      2.5             2                2
11:    3 2015-01-05       B      b     5 2015-01-02 2015-01-07      5.0             1                2
12:    1 2015-01-06       A      a     2 2015-01-01 2015-01-06      2.5             2                2
13:    2 2015-01-06       A      b     3 2015-01-04 2015-01-07      2.5             2                2
14:    3 2015-01-06       B      b     5 2015-01-02 2015-01-07      5.0             2                2
15:    4 2015-01-06       B      c     5 2015-01-06 2015-01-07      5.0             2                2
16:    2 2015-01-07       A      b     3 2015-01-04 2015-01-07      3.0             1                2
17:    3 2015-01-07       B      b     5 2015-01-02 2015-01-07      5.0             2                2
18:    4 2015-01-07       B      c     5 2015-01-06 2015-01-07      5.0             2                2
```

I have not been able to find anything related on here apart from the solution I had thought of myself, however, if there is a reference would be a great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really must avoid that join because it will blow up for larger data. You could try if this loop is fast enough (the number of dates is probably not huge, I wouldn't expect more than about three to four thousand max).

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(company = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), 
                 person = c("a", "b", "b", "c"), 
                 value = c(2,3,5,5), 
                 start_date = c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-02", "2015-01-06"), 
                 end_date = c("2015-01-06", "2015-01-07", "2015-01-07", "2015-01-07"))
DT[, c("start_date", "end_date") := lapply(.(start_date, end_date), as.Date)]
dates <- DT[, seq(from = min(start_date), to = max(end_date), by = "day")]
res <- lapply(dates, function(x) {
  d <- x
  DT[, .(date = d,  mean_EPS = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE), .N), by = .(company, x >= start_date & x <= end_date)][x == TRUE]
})

res <- rbindlist(res)
#    company    x       date mean_EPS N
# 1:       A TRUE 2015-01-01      2.0 1
# 2:       A TRUE 2015-01-02      2.0 1
# 3:       B TRUE 2015-01-02      5.0 1
# 4:       A TRUE 2015-01-03      2.0 1
# 5:       B TRUE 2015-01-03      5.0 1
# 6:       A TRUE 2015-01-04      2.5 2
# 7:       B TRUE 2015-01-04      5.0 1
# 8:       A TRUE 2015-01-05      2.5 2
# 9:       B TRUE 2015-01-05      5.0 1
#10:       A TRUE 2015-01-06      2.5 2
#11:       B TRUE 2015-01-06      5.0 2
#12:       A TRUE 2015-01-07      3.0 1
#13:       B TRUE 2015-01-07      5.0 2

res[, .N, by = date]
#         date N
#1: 2015-01-01 1
#2: 2015-01-02 2
#3: 2015-01-03 2
#4: 2015-01-04 2
#5: 2015-01-05 2
#6: 2015-01-06 2
#7: 2015-01-07 2
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution is indeed faster, than my solution. Up until about 100 thousand rows in the test dataset, it works well, however, my total dataset is close to 1 million rows. Is there any optimisation possible, or is patience key in this instance?

Comment: @Hjalmar I think I would quickly write something in Rcpp. It should be pretty simple. You could also parallelize the `lapply` loop (I'd look into the Rdsm package since it offers shared memory). There might also be a more clever solution with data.table (or even some package for bioinformatics), but I don't have time to investigate that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
    df =df%>%as.tibble()%>%
      transmute(Date = map2(start_date, end_date, seq, by = "day"), company,person,value) %>%
      unnest()  

    df1=df%>%group_by(Date,company)%>%
      summarize(mean_value=mean(value),Number_people=n_distinct(person))%>%
      right_join(df,by=c("company","Date"))

    df2=df%>%
      group_by(Date)%>%
      summarize(companies=n_distinct(company))%>%
      right_join(df1,by="Date")%>%
      arrange(Date)
    df2
 Date       companies company mean_value Number_people person value
   <date>         <int> <chr>        <dbl>         <int> <chr>  <dbl>
 1 2015-01-01         1 A              2               1 a          2
 2 2015-01-02         2 A              2               1 a          2
 3 2015-01-02         2 B              5               1 b          5
 4 2015-01-03         2 A              2               1 a          2
 5 2015-01-03         2 B              5               1 b          5
 6 2015-01-04         2 A              2.5             2 a          2
 7 2015-01-04         2 A              2.5             2 b          3
 8 2015-01-04         2 B              5               1 b          5
 9 2015-01-05         2 A              2.5             2 a          2
10 2015-01-05         2 A              2.5             2 b          3
11 2015-01-05         2 B              5               1 b          5
12 2015-01-06         2 A              2.5             2 a          2
13 2015-01-06         2 A              2.5             2 b          3
14 2015-01-06         2 B              5               2 b          5
15 2015-01-06         2 B              5               2 c          5
16 2015-01-07         2 A              3               1 b          3
17 2015-01-07         2 B              5               2 b          5
18 2015-01-07         2 B              5               2 c          5
```